# Formatting price data

Tags: list-manipulation

I am import some data from a CSV file.  I want to replace the ":" and "-" so I can graph it with `ListLinePlot` or `DateListPlot`.  Here is what I have tried:

```
mydata = Import["C:\\data\\py_data\\QCL#.csv", "CSV"];
dat = ToExpression@StringSplit[mydata, {",", \n, "-"}]
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.  I can't see a way to attach a file so I have updated the question with the format.  Thank you.

```
2015-01-01 20:00:00,54.75,54.17,54.57,54.24,7787,2777
2015-01-01 21:00:00,54.45,54.06,54.27,54.06,11195,3358
2015-01-01 22:00:00,54.13,53.72,54.07,53.90,14379,3155
2015-01-01 23:00:00,53.97,53.80,53.88,53.92,15881,1498
2015-01-02 00:00:00,54.05,53.76,53.92,53.77,18440,2532
2015-01-02 01:00:00,53.92,53.77,53.77,53.91,19420,965
2015-01-02 02:00:00,53.95,53.77,53.90,53.82,20060,637
```

Chris

Comment: Chris, I suggest you delete the comment and put a small sample of `mydata` in the question (e.g., `mydata[[1;;5]]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple, version-9-compatible approach is simply to use `DateList`, which correctly interprets the string automatically.

Once you have imported your data into Mathematica and gotten it into a matrix like this (which I've called `rawdata`):

```
{{"2015-01-01 20:00:00", "54.75", "54.17", "54.57", "54.24", "7787", 
  "2777"}, {"2015-01-01 21:00:00", "54.45", "54.06", "54.27", "54.06",
   "11195", "3358"}, {"2015-01-01 22:00:00", "54.13", "53.72", 
  "54.07", "53.90", "14379", "3155"}, {"2015-01-01 23:00:00", "53.97",
   "53.80", "53.88", "53.92", "15881", 
  "1498"}, {"2015-01-02 00:00:00", "54.05", "53.76", "53.92", "53.77",
   "18440", "2532"}, {"2015-01-02 01:00:00", "53.92", "53.77", 
  "53.77", "53.91", "19420", "965"}, {"2015-01-02 02:00:00", "53.95", 
  "53.77", "53.90", "53.82", "20060", "637"}}
```

Then this will do the job (note the use of `SlotSequence`)

```
fixeddata = {DateList[#1], Sequence @@ ToExpression /@ {##2}} & @@@ rawdata
```

If your numbers are not coming out as strings, then the `Sequence @@ ToExpression` bit is not needed and you only need

```
fixeddata = {DateList[#1], ##2} & @@@ rawdata
```

Plotting is as easy as:

```
DateListPlot[fixeddata[[All, {1, 3}]], Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 7):

Mathematica has a built-in data type for dates/timestamps that can be constructed using [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateObject.html), which accepts string formats.

```
data = "2015-01-01 20:00:00,54.75,54.17,54.57,54.24,7787,2777
  2015-01-01 21:00:00,54.45,54.06,54.27,54.06,11195,3358
  2015-01-01 22:00:00,54.13,53.72,54.07,53.90,14379,3155
  2015-01-01 23:00:00,53.97,53.80,53.88,53.92,15881,1498
  2015-01-02 00:00:00,54.05,53.76,53.92,53.77,18440,2532
  2015-01-02 01:00:00,53.92,53.77,53.77,53.91,19420,965
  2015-01-02 02:00:00,53.95,53.77,53.90,53.82,20060,637";
data = ImportString[data, "CSV"] // Transpose;
data[[1]] = DateObject /@ data[[1]];

DateListPlot[
 Thread[{First[data], #}] & /@ Rest[data],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT**: I didn't know about `TemporalData` until I read mfvonh's answer. Since I like it a lot, here's another `TemporalData` solution:

```
data = ImportString[data, "CSV"] // Transpose;
data = TemporalData[#, {First[data]}] & /@ data;
DateListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Note that `TemporalData` will by itself convert the string timestamp, no intervention necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am getting an error with the code you suggested.  I am importing the data diffently.  Using: data = Import["C:\\data\\py_data\\QCL#.csv", "CSV"]; to build the array     The error is: DateListPlot::dtvals: Unable to automatically determine horizontal coordinates for the given data and DataRange.

Comment: @ChrisF What version of Mathematica are you using? Did you go through the steps one by one and check in which step the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

On Version 10 you can also use `SemanticImportString`.

```
SemanticImportString[
  data,
  Delimiters -> ","];
```

`TemporalData` provides a convenient wrapper for sequences of time series indexed against the same axis.

```
%[Transpose /* (TemporalData[Rest @ #, {First @ #}] &)];

DateListPlot[%, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I got an error that Transpose/*Reverse/*  gave me:  Syntax::sntxf: "Transpose/" cannot be followed by "*Reverse/*(TemporalData[Most@#,{Last@#}]&)".; Syntax::tsntxi: "Transpose/" is incomplete; more input is needed.;  Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .  Thank you

Comment: This syntax was introduced in version 10 -- are you using a lower version?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.  I am using v9 , I couldn't afford the premium support this year.  Can you recommend a workaround that will work with the older version?  Thank you